# How to pass value to function using DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a C# web MVC app that has a dropdownlist with 2 items as follows:

Current version
Previous version

When the dropdownlist is selected the versionData java script function is currently being called but I can’t seem to get the selected item value passed in the function:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Items, Model.Items,"",new {ng_model="versionid " , ng_change="VersionData(versionid) })"
```

Depending on the item selected a value should be passed to the function.

Example :
current version: value = v1 
Previous version: value = v2

So when the  functioning is called it should pass a value like… `VersionData(v1)….`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get the value in the JavaScript function you are calling using jQuery?

So you could do:

```
function VersionData() {
    $("DropdownListName").find(":selected").text()
}
```

Comment: How would I get the DropdownListName/id?

Comment: I have done this before by just looking at the generated element in my web browsers development tools. Or you can specify it in the HtmlAttributes like: `Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SomeProperty, new {@id="UniqueID1234", @name="MyName"});`